# How To Append <span></span> Tags To special Word by click the word pargraph

Tags: html, jquery

After clicking on the second word, change the tag of the first word directly to the second word, leaving the first word without any tags

<html>

<p>

The word hashtag is in this sentence.

</p>

</html>

```
function replaceText() {
    $("*").each(function() { 
        if($(this).children().length==0) { 
           $(this).html($(this).text().replace('hashtag', '<span style="color: red;">hashtag</span>'));
        } 
    });
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

Comment: Do you mean: when you click the word "word", wrap the `hashtag` word in a `span`?

Comment: any word of paragraph just appends tag after clicked the second word remove tag first word clicked append tag second word click.